# Use Adblock to allow most ads on a site

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, advertisements, adblock

I leave Adblock turned on for all sites by default. I allow ads on some sites. You can do this by adding an exception for a site that is allowed to show ads. This puts a site in the white list.

However, I do not know how to allow most ads on a page, but block a specific ad. I am not even sure Adblock will do this. I believe it is all or none. If a site is in the white list, it appears that all other rules are ignored.

Is there a way to allow most ads on a website, but still block specific ads?

Comment: Didn't Jeff answer this question at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28149/advertising-on-stack-overflow-and-adblock/28243#28243 already? 
So: block all + allow exception + block specific image = answer?

Comment: Per my comments on that question and the question above, as far as I know you are not able to do that on a whitelisted page.

Comment: I have this very site whitelisted, and no, you can't block elements on a whitelisted page.

Comment: Of course I tried. I tried that before I even posted the original question. My google fu is not weak. Asking a question is the absolute last resort for me.

Comment: @CarlF Can you add a answer to that effect?

Comment: Aha, on my Mac's Firefox the option to block specific images seems to be missing as well. Using a Mac by any chance? (So, my right-click menu is different from Jeff's screen capture.)

Comment: On XP. What Jeff suggests works all the time on sites that are not whitelisted, but will not work in sites that are whitelisted.

Comment: But in Jeff's screen capture, Adblock has been disabled for that site as well (or for all sites)...

Comment: I am at work... I can't see the image he as provided. With Adblock set to disable on a site, I get no options to block anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, on my computer<sup>†</sup>, [Jeff's instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28149/advertising-on-stack-overflow-and-adblock/28243#28243) only work in a specific order, and in the end indeed have no effect:

1. Enable Adblock Plus
2. Browse to some site, right-click the Adblock icon and choose "*Disable on [..]*"
3. Right-click some image (for easy testing: preferably the site's logo), and choose the option "*Adblock Plus: Block image...*" (also note the option "*Adblock Plus: Re-enable on this page...*")
4. Refresh the page
5. The image that was blocked in step 3, will still show
6. Right-click some other image, and see that the option to block a specific image is gone
7. Re-enable Adblock for that website
8. Refresh the page
9. The blocked image will no longer show
10. Left-click the Adblock icon, and remove the rule from step 3 from "My Ad Blocking Rules"

I have not yet found [a bug report](http://adblockplus.org/en/bugs) on this. Can anyone confirm seeing the menu item in step 3 (and not in step 6)?

(I guess @CarlF and @jrob already confirmed step 5.)

---

<sup>†</sup> Mac OS X 10.6.1, Firefox 3.5.4, Adblock Plus 1.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your direct question, but I can give you an alternative.

[Opera](http://www.opera.com) has a built-in content blocking tool that lets you selectively choose content from certain hosts to be disabled.  You right-click on a page, select Block Content, then you click on anything on the page to add that content to the block list.

Answer (score 0):

You can block specific URLs by specifying the full path:

> http://sstatic.net/su/img/logo.png

as opposed to:

> http://sstatic.net/su/img/*.png

or:

> http://sstatic.net/*

to use the logo of Super User as an example.

Comment: Adding the exception rule does not seem to make a difference. If it is whitelisted, even the exception rule makes no difference.

Comment: Odd - I'm sure I've used the exception rule in the past.